# Send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```js
function withdraw() public payable {
  msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

I wrote this code and I got "ERROR send and transfer are only available for objects of type address payable , not address.".

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful, or do you need more help?

Answer (score 3):

Only the `payable address` type has the `transfer` method. `msg.sender` is the `address` type so you need to cast it to be `payable`:

```js
payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> The address type comes in two flavours, which are largely identical:
>
> - **address**: Holds a 20 byte value (size of an Ethereum address).
> - **address payable**: Same as address, but with the additional members > transfer and send.

You need to cast it to an `address payable` type to use the `send` and `transfer` methods. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/types.html#address for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
   address payable private owner;
```

then set the owner in constructor as msg.sender:

```
constructor() {
    setOwner(msg.sender);
  }
```

this is setOwner:

```
function setOwner(address newOwner) private {
    owner = payable(newOwner);
  }
```

this is withdraw function:

```
 function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
     (bool success,)=owner.call{value:address(this).balance}("");
    // if it is not success, throw error
     require(success,"Transfer failed!");
   }
```

Make sure only owner can call this so write a modifier:

```
 modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != getContractOwner()) {
      revert OnlyOwner();
    }
    _;
  }
```

`revert OnlyOwner` is sending custom message with newer versions of solidity:

```
/// Only owner has an access!
  error OnlyOwner();
```